# Can not read data from local MongoDB using expressjs mongoose library

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am learning Mongoose and MongoDB and try to read data from a local hosted MongoDB, I typed similar example from Mongoose documentation. But it doesn't work.
I create a simple MongoDB collection named `blogs` inside a database called `personal_website` for test purposes. And there is only one document in this collection

```
personal_website> db.blogs.find()
[ { _id: ObjectId("63bbcb27ae437ded486fecf4"), title: 'test' } ]
```

There is my code which doesn't work

```
user@user-machine: ~$ cat server.js

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/personal_website", () => {
    console.log("connected to databse personal_website");
});

let blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
});

let Blog = mongoose.model("blog", blogSchema);

let blogCount = Blog.find({}).count();
console.log(blogCount);
```

I run `node server.js` but I got this output:

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map(0) {}, _posts: Map(0) {} },
  _executionStack: null,
.........
connected to databse personal_website
```

I expect get the similar result as i run `db.blogs.find().count()` command in MongoDB shell. How could I fix that? Should I query database after the connection established? I saw a lot of tutorials connect to their MongoDB at the very beginning just like me and also the documentation says *"Mongoose lets you start using your models immediately, without waiting for mongoose to establish a connection to MongoDB"*. So can you guys help me figure out what cause this problem and how to fix it? I really appreciate that, I stuck there like four hours.

Comment: You didn't execute the query. Use `exec` with a callback or you can also use `async/await` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use port number and `127.0.0.1` in your connection string:
   `"mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/personal_website"` instead of `"mongodb://localhost/personal_website"` (27017 is default port)
2. try to wrap your query with async function and use await:

```
async function count() {
  let blogCount = await Blog.find({}).count();
  console.log(blogCount);
}

count();
```

Comment: I changed my code and get a new error message: `MongooseError: Operation blogs.count() buffering timed out after 10000ms`. I checked the port that mongodb is learning to is `27017`

Comment: when you run `server.js` file do you see `"connected to databse personal_website"` message?

Comment: I figure out why it didn't work, i should use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: I thought they are the same. Anyway I will also edit my answer so that it will be useful for others.